# Autoplay tag in mobile not working

Tags: html, css

I tried to **autoplay** video in mobile I tried **video** tag and also **iframe** but it didn't worked. How can I fix this, or can someone suggest me the alternative for the same?

Here is my code

Comment: `<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="" muted="" controls="" poster="images/slider-1.jpg">
    <source src="bmwslider.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="bmwslider.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>`

Comment: Code in comments is not readable, you can always edit your own question and format the source code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Add muted to your video-tag. Videos with active audio arent allowed to autoplay on mobile.
Also i wouldnt recommend autoplay in mobile applications.